# How to set object's function parameter optional in php oop

Tags: php, oop

I want something like this in a class structure:

```
$public $choice;

function __construct(){
    $this->set_login($this->choice);
}

private function set_login($this->choice){
    if($this->choice=='2'){
       // don't set login credentials
    }else{
       // set login credentials
    }
}
```

The above code requires $choice to be set every time before I initialize the class.
But I want to set $choice as optional parameter.
I want if in any page, I call like this:

```
 $login = new login();
```

that class will set login credentials normally but if called like this:

```
  $login = new login();
  $login->choice = 2;
```

then login credentials will not be set.

I am not sure, whether the class will be executed in such way because as soon as I initialize the class, the __construct method will be called and the $choice to be set at that time. But if I set $choice after initialization, then will the code work?

How can I make a parameter optional in oop?

Comment: What language is this ==> how to set a default value depends on the programming language you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell that. It is for php. I have edited the question title.

Comment: Parameter optional as in giving it a default value? Second, the given PHP is not valid at all, therefor it will be considered as pseudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define you method `set_login` as:

```
public function set_login($choice = 1) {
    if ($choice == 2) {
       // don't set login credentials
    } else {
       // set login credentials
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
$login = new login();

// Login.
$login->set_login();
// Doesn't login.
$login->set_login(2);
```

**EDIT:**

Another solution:

```
private $choice;

function __construct($choice = false) {
    $this->set_login($choice);

    // If you want to remember the choice, you can save it in a property:
    $this->choice = $choice; 
}

private function set_login($choice) {
    if ($choice == 2) {
       // don't set login credentials
    } else {
       // set login credentials
    }
}
```

Note that the following code will never work as you expect because you change the value of choice after executing the method `set_login` in the constructor:

```
$login = new login();
$login->choice = 2;
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your reply. Your answer is close to my intention by not exactly what I want to do. I want to keep set_login as private. I want to set option from class parameter and set_login has to be called from __construct. But if I use set_login directly (public), in that case if I set it like this way: set_login($choice=FALSE), will it be right way?